# Need help understanding the scope of my variables in relation to my methods

Tags: java, methods, scope

I'm making a fake play by play for a basketball game for school. The program works at the moment, but I'm not sure why. I put the name, team and number variables in for the arguments when calling my shoot and dribble methods, but how does it know that I want the playerName, playerTeam and playerNumber variables stored in the player objects and not the default ones from the main method? I'm probably getting this all wrong, so any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
//This program creates a play by play of a basketball game
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*; //for randomizer
class PlayByPlayTester{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{
        InputStreamReader inStream = new InputStreamReader(System.in);
        BufferedReader stdin = new BufferedReader(inStream);
        
        //declare variables
        String name, team, number;
        
        //title
        System.out.println("Basketball Play By Play");
        
        //gets all 4 players' info and sets them
        System.out.println("Enter a player's name");
        name = stdin.readLine();
        System.out.println("Enter player's number");
        number = stdin.readLine();
        System.out.println("Enter player's team");
        team = stdin.readLine();
        Basketball player1 = new Basketball(name, team, number);
        
        System.out.println("Enter a new player's name");
        name = stdin.readLine();
        System.out.println("Enter  the new player's number");
        number = stdin.readLine();
        System.out.println("Enter the new player's team");
        team = stdin.readLine();
        Basketball player2 = new Basketball(name, team, number);
        
        System.out.println("Enter a new player's name");
        name = stdin.readLine();
        System.out.println("Enter the new player's number");
        number = stdin.readLine();
        System.out.println("Enter the new player's team");
        team = stdin.readLine();
        Basketball player3 = new Basketball(name, team, number);
        
        System.out.println("Enter a new player's name");
        name = stdin.readLine();
        System.out.println("Enter the new player's number");
        number = stdin.readLine();
        System.out.println("Enter the new player's team");
        team = stdin.readLine();
        Basketball player4 = new Basketball(name, team, number);
        
        //randomized play by play
        for(int count = 0; count <= 10; count++){
            //gets random numbers
            double actionRandomizer = Math.random(); 
            double playerRandomizer = Math.random();
            
            //chooses which player to display based on random number
            if(playerRandomizer <= 0.25){
                if(actionRandomizer <= 0.5){
                    player1.dribble(name, team, number);
                }else{
                    player1.shoot(name, team, number);
                }
            }
            if(playerRandomizer <= 0.5 && playerRandomizer > 0.25){
                if(actionRandomizer <= 0.5){
                    player2.dribble(name, team, number);
                }else{
                    player2.shoot(name, team, number);
                }
            }
            if(playerRandomizer <= 0.75 && playerRandomizer > 0.5){
                if(actionRandomizer <= 0.5){
                    player3.dribble(name, team, number);
                }else{
                    player3.shoot(name, team, number);
                }
            }
            if(playerRandomizer < 1 && playerRandomizer > 0.75){
                if(actionRandomizer <= 0.5){
                    player4.dribble(name, team, number);
                }else{
                    player4.shoot(name, team, number);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

class Basketball{
    
    //declare instance variables
    private String playerName, playerTeam, playerNumber;
    
    //dribble method
    public void dribble(String nameIn, String teamIn, String numberIn){
        System.out.println(playerName + " #" + playerNumber + " of the " + playerTeam + " dribbles the ball.");
    }
    //shoot method
    public void shoot(String nameIn, String teamIn, String numberIn){
        System.out.println(playerName + " #" + playerNumber + " of the " + playerTeam + " shoots the ball.");
    }
    
    //player constructor
    Basketball(String nameIn, String teamIn, String numberIn){
        playerName = nameIn;
        playerTeam = teamIn;
        playerNumber = numberIn;
    }
}
```

Comment: Because the variables you pass in are called `nameIn`, `teamIn`, and `numberIn`, whereas the variables you're using are called `playerName`, `playerNumber`, and `playerTeam`. Why would the computer mistake the latter for the former, when they have different names? (It's generally good practice to not include parameters that your code doesn't use)

Comment: Yeah I just realized my mistake, I didn't realize that I didn't need parameters for the output, thanks for your help!